# Does SOP restriction apply to UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I wrote an html game, I'm packaging the html file in an ios app. The ios app will just load the page from disk and render it in a UIWebView.

Do same-origin-policy restrictions apply in this setup (assuming yes)?

For example, I want the game to hit my webserver for multiplayer, but that should be a different domain than where the html page was loaded from (local disk in the app space).

If SOP applies, is there any way around it for a native ios app like this? Could I disable it on UIWebView?

I could implement JSONP on my webserver, but if there was a way to disable this at the app level it might be a lot easier,

Thanks

Comment: I would hope SOP applies but resources from file:// have notoriously lax SOPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at CORs
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

It will be very easy to set it up on your webserver

Comment: Hmm yeah that does look like a better solution. For some reason I thought CORs was very new, but looks like it's been around since 2009. Thanks